# Find specific day / time in previous week

Tags: rust

I am using Rust with the Chrono library, and need to find the DateTime for the previous Tuesday at 6 PM UTC.

I have the following code, which seems to be working, but seems more complicated than it should be.

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc, Duration, Datelike};
use chrono::prelude::*;
fn main() {

    let now: DateTime<Utc> = Utc::now();
    let n_date = Utc::now().date();
    let dt = Utc.ymd(n_date.year(), n_date.month(), n_date.day()).and_hms(18, 0, 0);

    let current_day = now.weekday().number_from_monday();
    let target_dt = if current_day == 2 {
        if dt > now {
            dt
        } else {
            dt - Duration::days(7)
        }
    }
    else if current_day > 2 {
        dt - Duration::days((current_day - 2) as i64)
    } else {
        dt - Duration::days(6)
    };

    println!("{:?}", target_dt);
}
```

Is there more efficient / better way to find a specific DateTime in the previous week? (In this case, the previous Tuesday at 18:00 UTC). Looking at some other languages, there are one line solutions, and I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Based on the feedback below, here is the updated code:

```
    let now: DateTime<Utc> = Utc::now();
    //use this to test specific dates / times
    //let now : DateTime<Utc> = Utc.ymd(2020, 11, 24).and_hms(18, 0, 1);

    let n_date = now.date();
    //let n_date =  Utc.ymd(2020, 11, 24).and_hms(17, 0, 0).date();

    let dt = Utc.ymd(n_date.year(), n_date.month(), n_date.day()).and_hms(18, 0, 0);

    let w_day = n_date.weekday();
    let target_dt = if w_day == Weekday::Tue {
        if now > dt {
            dt
        } else {
            dt - Duration::days(7)
        }
    } else {
        let c:i64 = ((w_day.num_days_from_sunday() + 4) % 7 + 1) as i64;
        dt - Duration::days(c)
    };

println!("{:?}", target_dt);
```

ok. After thinking about this more, I figured out a more straight forward way, that plays off the fact that I can use a previous know reset data / time as a reference:

```
pub const WEEK_IN_SECONDS: i64 = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

pub fn get_last_reset() -> DateTime<Utc> {
    //get a hardcoded past reset date / time
    let past_reset : DateTime<Utc> = Utc.ymd(2020, 11, 10).and_hms(18, 0, 0);
    let now: DateTime<Utc> = Utc::now();

    //get total seconds between now and the past reset
    //take the mod of that divided by a week in seconds
    //subtract that amount from current date / time to find previous reset
    now - Duration::seconds((now - past_reset).num_seconds() % WEEK_IN_SECONDS)
}
```

Comment: `if dt > now {
            dt
        }` If today is a Tuesday morning/after noon ( less than 1800) then return today 1800 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By shamelessly stealing ideas of both [@MaxV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65032747/8564999) and [@Simson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65032079/find-specific-day-time-in-previous-week#comment114972264_65032747) you can do the following: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=479975fa720cc137aed2e9d78f9d75f4)
Fixed it to cover time below or above 18 hours on Tuesday

```
use chrono::{Utc, Duration, NaiveTime};
use chrono::prelude::*;
fn main() {
    let now: DateTime<Utc> = Utc.ymd(2020, 11, 25).and_hms(17, 0, 0);
    let now_date = now.date();
    let current_day = now_date.weekday().number_from_monday() as i64;
    let tuesday_correction = if current_day == 2 && now.time() < NaiveTime::from_hms(18, 0, 0) {7} else {0};
    let days_to_tuesday = Duration::days((7 + current_day - 2) % 7 + tuesday_correction);
    let target_date = (now_date - days_to_tuesday).and_hms(18, 0, 0);
    println!("{:?}", target_date);
}
```

Comment: I dont think this works on the Tuesday, after 18:00.

Set now date to this, and it points to the previous tuesday (a week earlier), and not the same day at 18:00

let now_date =  Utc.ymd(2020, 11, 24).and_hms(20, 0, 0).date();

Comment: The code and the description of what should happen after 1800 on Tuesdays are not fully clear.

Comment: @mikechambers fixed it, let me know if you need further explanations

Comment: Thanks! That works, and is a cleaner than what I had. Marked it as the answer.

Comment: I updated my original post with another solution / approach that I think is a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There is my solution for `Tuesday 18:00`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f666780942eefb5bce69122ef87cb336)

```
use chrono::{Utc, Duration, Datelike, Date};

fn main() {
    let now: Date<Utc> = Utc::now().date();
    
    let days_since_previous_tue = match now.weekday().number_from_monday() {
        /*Mon*/ 1 => 6,
        /*Tue*/ 2 => 7,
        /*Wed*/ 3 => 1,
        /*Thu*/ 4 => 2,
        /*Fri*/ 5 => 3,
        /*Sat*/ 6 => 4,
        /*Sun*/ 7 => 5,
        _ => panic!("Incorrect number_from_monday"),
    };
    
    let target = (now - Duration::days(days_since_previous_tue)).and_hms(18, 0, 0);
    
    println!("Target date:{:?}", target); 
}
```

It's not generic enough to process any possible day but I believe it shows the idea. Please let me know if you're interested in generic solution for any day/time.

Comment: Is this not an implementation of `(day + 4 %) 7 +1`

Comment: For sure. It may be interesting to compare which one is faster.

Comment: Thanks. This works, unless its a tuesday after 18:00. i.e. let now =  Utc.ymd(2020, 11, 24).and_hms(20, 0, 0).date();